# Get value from element JavaScript, error:implicitly-typed variable

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am trying to get a value from an input element by using JavaScript. 
But I get this error "Cannot Assign void to an implicitly-typed variable."
when trying to assign the value to a variable

This is how I'm trying to get it work,

```
public static void JsGetElementText(this IWebElement element, Browser browser)
        {
            if (browser.Driver is IJavaScriptExecutor)
            {
                var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)browser.Driver;
                js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value;", element);
            }
            else
            {
                element.Click();
            }
     }



  var value = txtInputField.JsGetElementText(Browser); // here is where the error is. 


[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input")]
IWebElement txtInputField{ get; set; }
```

There is no problem to write to the input field, but getting the value that's been inputted is harder :)

I tried `return element.Text` but since Input Element does not show inputed value as text, i thought that maybe JavaScript could solve the problem.

Any Ideas?

Comment: the example you provided has two parameters in the function but only passes one parameter on the line "where the error is". Also the error is stating that the return type of the function is `void` which is what would be assigned to `var value`. Probably just need to adjust the return type of the function and return the appropriate value accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is just `string value = txtInputField.GetAttribute("value");`. You don't need that function.

Comment: You are complete right, I was overthinking it!.
Thank you.